# Counting nan in a pandas series - when will this way fail?

Tags: python, count, nan

There are a lot of posts about how to count `NaN` in a list or pandas series, as well as the time efficiency of the various options. One solution I have not seen is self equality: If `y == np.nan` then `(y != y) is True`. So a quick way to count the NaNs in a list would be:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst = pd.Series([np.nan, 5, 4, 3, 2, np.nan])
count = sum(1 for x in lst if x != x)
```

I hadn't seen that solution before, which makes me wonder: When will this fail to work the way I want it to work (eg maybe for dtypes that aren't in my columns - I have floats and strings? I've done some testing with my own data, and found this solution to be equivalent to:

```py
count = lst.isnull().sum()
# and
count = len([x for x in lst if x != x])
```

I've found that the speed is in this order from fastest to slowest: `sum`, `len`, `.sum()`

Comment: One possible downside I see to this approach is the creation of a new object, with the processing time and power for `len(col)` list.append operations plus the memory storage for the whole column to basically be duplicated. Not a concern for a small df, but what if you have 217 columns and 10M rows? If you check each row and column, you've essentially made a boolean copy of your df in memory

Comment: Good comment. For my dataset, I iterate across millions of columns but only have about 40 rows, so each iteration I'm overwriting the `count` object. for `pd.Series().isnull()` - doesn't that create a boolean series as well though?

Comment: Under the hood, I couldn't say whether it recreates the list, but a good rule of thumb is that generally the built-in functions are optimized to run at the numpy, Cython, and/or C level, which generally makes them more memory and processing efficient compared to the manual equivalent. Additionally, though you're overwriting the variable in each run, you're still doing 40,000,000+ `append` calls, and depending on your implementation you're relying on the default garbage collection to clear the memory for `lst` rather than hold the memory and create a new object with the same pointer

Comment: In iPython/jupyter, you can use the `%timeit` magic to time the difference between the two operations, or do some profiling to see the number of calls each makes to help visualize the efficiency difference

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`numpy.isnan()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), so your code would look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst = pd.Series([np.nan, 5, 4, 3, 2, np.nan])
count = len([x for x in lst if np.isnan(x)])
```

But if you want to be fancy:

```py
count = sum(np.isnan(lst))
```

Or if you're concerned about memory:

```py
# Less elegant, but does the job
count = 0
for x in lst:
    if np.isnan(x):
        count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks! That was one of the options I've timed in tests. The `sum` generator above was faster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I did a basic time complexity experiment between the two proposed methods. Note that this doesn't address any cases where your approach fails, as I didn't find any.

Setup:

```
def make_col():
    return [np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,np.NaN]) for i in range(100000)]

df=pd.DataFrame({k:make_ops() for k in list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')})

df.shape
(100000, 26)
```

Experiment (note that I tried to be explicit at each step rather than optimizing for total efficiency, to show the difference between the two):

```
%%timeit
n=[]
for col in df.columns:
    count=len([x for x in df[col] if x != x])
    n.append(count)
134 ms

%%timeit
n=[]
for col in df.columns:
    count=count = df[col].isnull().sum()
    n.append(count)
29.7 ms
```

For approximately 80% improvement using the built-in methods

Interestingly, based on the numpy/Cython/C optimization under the hood, if you run the `%%prun` profiler on both of the above operations, you get fewer individual function calls with your approach, but more overall runtime.
Respectively:

```
2013 function calls in 0.248 seconds
```

vs.

```
8903 function calls in 0.046 seconds
```

And, regarding memory usage between the two, it looks like you're right regarding the two being logically equivalent regarding copying and storage. Both snippets above come in around

`peak memory: 247.20 MiB`

using the `%%memit` magic from [this source](https://ipython-books.github.io/44-profiling-the-memory-usage-of-your-code-with-memory_profiler/) (which as a caveat, I haven't seen or used previously and am unaware of any gotchas or issues regarding its use)

Comment: Thanks! In my tests, the `sum` generator was faster than using `len`. Can you replicate? (I also see `count=count = ` in the second test, assuming this was a copy/paste errror) 

I guess i hadn't included the sum generator in my post. I've edited it now.

Comment: Yes, that was an error. I see the following: `count=sum((x for x in df[col] if x != x)) 128 ms`, `count=sum([x for x in df[col] if x != x]) 115 ms`, `count=len([x for x in df[col] if x != x]) 114 ms`. But over multiple runs with the same test data, all varied within the same range. Also noted, my test data is long, while you stated yours is wide, so that may make a difference.